# On application I write "I, Sushanta Majhi, a student of your school state that" so is it correct

Tags: british-english

On application I write "I,  Sushanta Majhi, a student of your school state that" so is it correct,  should am be used as helping verb in-place of a.

Comment: It's probably more normal to use another comma: "I, Sushanta Majhi, a student of your school, state that..." but without knowing the full sentence it's hard to be sure.

Comment: You could write "I, Sushanta Majhi, am a student of your school and I state that...", but then you have two independent main clauses so it requires "and". Again, without knowing what follows it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It's grammatically correct.

It just would sound a little silly in most situations, as if you are writing a personal manifesto, and not an application. The use of the verb "state", since whatever you write is "stated" so it's unnecessary.  Your name and status are probably already known so the simpler replacement would be to cut this whole phrase and just write the thing that you "state".

Comment: Thanks...I have another question i.e  if name is used am will not be used